# hosting multiple Hangfire Dashboards in one application without running inside it any jobs

Tags: .net-core, hangfire

I created a single application that hosts multiple Hangfire Dashboards for several storages. and I'm trying to understand which configuration is required for Hangfire to make it work.
For each storage there is an additional application that schedules jobs so need to be able to run jobs from the dashboard application.

But I do want to be able to trigger recurring jobs from the Dashboard, so in that case do I need HangfireServer here?

When calling AddHangfire do I need to set the following -

```
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
```

When calling only AddHangfire and UseHangfireDashboard with the relevant storage it works.
But I'm not sure which configuration is need to be set for this purpose and how triggering a recurring job from the Dashboard is processed now and by who?